# multiple files rename - filenames patterns

Tags: terminal, rename, batch-jobs

I have following image files in some directory which I want to be renamed:

```
8 -rw-rw-r-- 1 6661 sep 24 10:28 dbConnectionOkBostjan.png
8 -rw-rw-r-- 1 6548 sep 24 10:29 dbConnectionErrorBostjan.png
8 -rw-rw-r-- 1 5708 sep 24 10:29 btConnectionErrorBostjan.png
8 -rw-rw-r-- 1 5911 sep 24 10:30 btConnectionOkBostjan.png
8 -rw-rw-r-- 1 6916 sep 24 10:31 userLogOkBostjan.png
8 -rw-rw-r-- 1 6924 sep 24 10:44 userLogErrorBostjan.png
```

Now, I know how to use `mv` command to rename file and I even know how to rename multiple files, but in this case I want to rename every this file with new name same as original file, but without word `Bostjan`. For example, `dbConnectionOkBostjan.png` must rename to `dbConnectionOk.png` and same for all other files. How do achieve this task using terminal? I wish to solve this using ordinary `mv` command. If I use proposed solution from **Answer 1**, I get following errors:

```
user@testcomp:~/Pictures/testAppIcons$ for i in *Bostjan*; do mv $i $(echo $i | sed @Bostjan@@); done sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `@' mv: missing destination file operand after ‘btConnectionErrorBostjan.png’ Try 'mv --help' for more information. sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `@' mv: missing destination file operand after ‘btConnectionOkBostjan.png’ Try 'mv
--help' for more information. sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `@' mv: missing destination file operand after ‘dbConnectionErrorBostjan.png’ Try 'mv --help' for more information. sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `@' mv: missing destination file operand after ‘dbConnectionOkBostjan.png’ Try 'mv
--help' for more information. sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `@' mv: missing destination file operand after ‘userLogErrorBostjan.png’ Try 'mv --help' for more information. sed:
-e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `@' mv: missing destination file operand after ‘userLogOkBostjan.png’ Try 'mv --help' for more information. user@testcomp:~/Pictures/testAppIcons$
```

I am using *KUbuntu 15.04*.

Comment: @Archemar I think this is not a duplicate since I want to solve this using `mv`, not `perl's rename`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That can be done in one line, though for legibility I'll split. I echo the filename and modify it using sed in the target argument of mv:

```
for i in *Bostjan*; do
  mv $i $(echo $i | sed s@Bostjan@@)
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mmv`. (You may have to install it first.)

`mmv "*Botsjan*" "#1#2"`